# Need an example of how to use flatMapPrefix in akka stream

Tags: akka-stream

I think i need that method but i am not sure how it works. Can someone give an example of its usage.

```
 def flatMapPrefix[Out2, Mat2](n: Int)(f: immutable.Seq[Out] => Flow[Out, Out2, Mat2]): Repr[Out2] = {
    via(new FlatMapPrefix(n, f))
  }
```

are the n first elements processed pass downstream too ? or only those coming after ?

Answer (score 2):

Only the elements coming later are passed to the flow created in the `flatMapPrefix`.

This will print 1 to 10:

```scala
Source(1 to 10)
    .runForeach(i => println(i))
```

Here we introduce a `Flow` that does nothing, so it will also print 1 to 10

```scala
  Source(1 to 10)
    .via(Flow[Int])
    .runForeach(i => println(i))
```

Here we use first 5 elements to create a `Flow` that will process the **rest** of the elements so it will print 6 to 10:

```scala
  Source(1 to 10)
    .flatMapPrefix(5) { l =>
      Flow[Int]
    }
    .runForeach(i => println(i))
```

Though we can still get those elements by using `prepend`. This prints 1 to 10:

```scala
  Source(1 to 10)
    .via(Flow[Int])
    .flatMapPrefix(5) { l =>
      Flow[Int]
        .prepend(Source(l))
    }
    .runForeach(i => println(i))
```

Comment: Thanks  but weird function !! No idea when that might be useful

Comment: Whenever your processing depends somehow on data in the flowing elements. Say if you have integer Source like in the examples and you want to multiply all the elements by the first element in the stream. It would be pretty tricky to do that without `flatMapPrefix` in one go.

Comment: Ah I see indeed cleaver stuff !! Thanks 